# can't split array of data coming from esp32 module server to Android Application. in java

Tags: java, android, performance, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

`I want to display data to Android Application  the data is coming from Esp32 module to Android Application  but I can't split this array its seems it string  and when I get the index value 9 ..its gave me array array index out of bound` 
**data = ups/testing/00.2/232/322/433/4323/332/32/332/332/543/453/3454/343/End this is Esp32 Server Module Data**

**I am sending this data from Docklight App**

***I want to split this data but its shows me Array index out of bound please help me this is my first job project and i want to do this task as soon as possible .

---

// this is my java code for Android Application

public void onCharacteristicChanged(final byte[] data) {

```
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String ipData = HexUtil.formatHexString(data);
                            Log.d(Tag+"OP",ipData);
                            if (ipData!=null) {
                                String [] data=ipData.split("/");
                                builderList.clear();
                                convertHaxToASCII(data);
                                setButtonText();
                                setText();
                                alarms.checkAlert(builderList.get(9).toString(), DetailBLE.this);
                            }

                            if (!builderList.isEmpty())
                            {
                                setTitle(builderList.get(1).toString());
                                setArrowsStatus();
                                setBatteryImage();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
```

**I want to split this data  data = ups/123/334/233/244/24/24/545/56/343/54634/454/End
as in the form of Array then i show this on user screen by indexing **
like for ups --get(0)

like for mains--get(1)
like for solar--get(2)
like for non solar--get(3)
like for battery low--get(4)
like for discharging current--get(5)